# Make bat file available everywhere for the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I have a bat file that I want to be able to call from everywhere, by simply calling it's name. In windows I simply had to add the folder where the .bat file is located, to the windows PATH. I have no idea how to do this in Ubuntu though. I'm guessing there's something similar..

Can someone explain how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to shortcut the program, and leave it where it is you can either use sym. links or the alias command.

(note this assumes you've made it executable, `chmod +x [script file]`)

**sym links** allow you to create a shortcut that behaves like the file in question.

```
sudo ln -s [script start-up file] /usr/bin/[name]
```

despite being in /usr/bin it will start in the directory you call it from.

**alias** allows you to give an name to a command, or series of piped commans, that you use regually, for example its fairly common to have the update/upgrade commands combined into a single, alias'd, one.

```
alias [name]="sh /path/to/script/[file name]"
```

assuming that your script runs with sh, (this could also be bash, for more complex tasks there is a difference).

Comment: +1 I use symlinks alot and forgot about them in my answer :D

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are no `bat` files for ubuntu, maybe you mean script files.

If you create a `bin` directory under your home, this will be automatically added to your `PATH`. Remember to give execution permissions to your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I use a folder in my home directory for this: `~/.local/bin`

That way, it's out of sight and all binary files that aren't system-wide I put in there, like small personal scripts that only I will be interested in running.

This method is also helpful for users who do not have system administrator permissions.

The `PATH` environment variable works in much the same way as it does on Windows, except paths are separated using colon (:) instead of semi-colon (;).

So, in short, run the following in a terminal (where "`$`" is the prompt):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
$ mv /path/to/executable/file ~/.local/bin/
```

then add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file (if you are running Bash as your shell):

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

If you are running a different shell, this final step may vary for you.

Answer (score 1):

Executables should be in `/usr/bin` so that solves your problem since this is inside your environment.

You can set a file to executable with the `chmod` command (sudo chmod 775 {filename}).
More info on the [permissions wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

The Ubuntu wiki on [Environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) will explain a lot about how settins can be set but there is no need for using this with just 1 script (Linux already got that covered).

Comment: Well this file depends on other files as well (it creates projects actually) so it would be easier if I could just leave it in my documents folder. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @sled sure! have a look at the Environment variables like I put in my answer. For example /etc/environment contains the system wide path. But there are more places to set a dir. But what you intend is more a windows way then a linux way ;) Security wise you should follow Linux's method.